# Linking to my website from my clients sites

Tags: seo, backlinks

When I create a website for my clients, I always by default add the following to the footer:

```
   <div class="websiteBy">
       <a href="http://www.example.co.uk" target="_blank">Website by<img src="assets/elements/loai-design-studio-logo.png"></a>
   </div>
```

Is what I am doing actually damaging me or my clients by anyway? I have researched and read few articles but they all are full of arguments and I really don't know which answer is right... also is it true - no-follow attribute need to be added?

Comment: That does not really answer my question....

Comment: "It is bad in context of Goolge's fighting with spam through "Penguin". This "Penguin" punishs for "site-wide" links. My piece of advice for you is to use rel="nofollow". It will prevent you from any filter actions but leave your link available for users."